# Wordpress shopping cart plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shopping-cart

I am looking for a shopping cart plugin works in wordpress where slideshow displays the parent category images upon click it should go to page of respective categories.
I want people to be able to log in and order products
Check the status of their order..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very vague and open-ended, with great potential for opinions to sway answers, but here are some great shopping carts for Wordpress. You can browse their features pages. I have personally used all of these (but have no interest/ownership in any of them at all):

[WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) (free) - by far the best I've used

[Cart66](http://cart66.com/) (paid)

[WP E-Commerce](http://getshopped.org/) (free) - works well for some - I've had some issues

Comment: Agreed, WooCommerce would be a great option. WP E-Commerece has been a little too unstable for me.